# Custom Toolbar With Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, custom-controls, uitoolbar

I'm planning to implement a custom toolbar using my own images. Something more or less exactly like [this](http://www.lovelyui.com/post/20592987385/music-player-on-madonna%5C) or [this](http://www.lovelyui.com/post/20418666273/navigation-on-zaarly). What would be required to do this. Could I just derive a control from UIView, then create another subclass to display the actual toolbar items and handle all the drawing myself in `drawRect`, or would it be better to make use of standard UIKit controls to handle the drawing of the images?

Comment: Are you sure you mean the Toolbar (second image: the bar on the top). Or do you mean the Tabbar (bar at the bottom)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get this to work the way I wanted was to use a custom control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a standard UITabBar - it is very customizable. You can set a custom `backgroundImage` and `selectionIndicatorImage` to completely change its looks. On the UITabBarItems, you can control the appearance using the `finishedSelectedImage` and `finishedUnselectedImage` properties.

Hope it helps, and good luck!

Comment: The problem is that I won't be using it to switch the ViewControllers inside a TabController, but rather to perform segues to different VCs and show popovers.